# How can some Christians deny devils and Hell exist?

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, hell, demons

As a person who believes in Jesus and the scriptures, I have encountered Christians who do not believe in devils, demons, Hell, and eternal punishment. That is despite these all being mentioned in the scriptures, even by Jesus, and devils and demons even being silenced and driven out by Jesus, and even the devil himself tempting Jesus.

I'd like to know what justification such Christians have for the stance which is most definitely not Biblical in its origin.

If you study the scriptures in respect of the words that Jesus spoke of, the two most common topics are the kingdom of Heaven and the kingdom of Hell. If you look at the killing of the first animal in Genesis by none other than Jesus Himself, you see him visually show humans that the price of sin is death. And that is why sin has to be paid for by blood. When the temporary sacrificial system for sin was introduced by God to the Hebrew people, it was to show people that sin is a very serious matter that leads to actual death.

Comment: No mini in the comments please.

Comment: This conflates two different doctrines. There are Christian denominations that believe (based on scripture) in the Devil and his demons, but they also believe (also based on scripture) that "Hell" is simply an old English word for "grave", where the unconscious bodies of the dead are buried, and that a loving God wouldn't subject anyone to perpetual torture (those that won't accept his offer of salvation will simply be destroyed). ¶ You might re-ask this as two separate questions, one about belief in Satan and demons, and one about Hell.  But first check that they haven't already been asked.

Comment: "*and the kingdom of Hell*" This phrase is found nowhere in the entire Bible. In fact, the word "hell" is found nowhere in the entire Bible, at least, not in the original Hebrew and Greek. The word traditionally translated "hell" is the word "Gehenna". In the KJV and a few others translations, the words Sheol, Hades, and Tartarus are also translated "hell" at times. But the word hell is found nowhere. That word comes from the Norse goddess of the underworld, hel. IMO, the word "Hell" should not be in English translations. Anyway, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that some people so interpret the Bible as to turn literal aspects of such things into symbols for something else that is non-literal.

You further ask how such persons are justified in their stance. Well, those who take this stance could answer at length, many of them using parts of the Bible to support their interpretations. To their way of thinking, they are perfectly justified.

It's not surprising that many Christians cannot understand why some people do not believe in devils and hell (as a place of eternal torment, I assume), but the only way to learn the answers is just to put your questions out there and allow responses. Your invitation for them to explain themselves may be taken up by some, but as I am not one of them, I cannot give a detailed answer.

Yet having come across many such people in my lifetime, I can add that such differences in views is down to how the Bible is interpreted, if, indeed, the Bible is even regarded as a sound basis for interpreting such beliefs. Many people who say there are no demons and no hell as a place of eternal torment also say the Bible is a motley collection of ancient stories and unreliable reports, mangled over the centuries because it was only fallible men writing and copying them. Once such a stance is taken, it's very easy to play fast and loose with the contents of the Bible, and with what they say it really teaches.

I'm just giving a basic answer because of the criteria for Stack Christianity; 'truth' questions are not 'allowed', nor are ones that seek opinions, or ones that will gender arguments. But if you really want to know detailed reasons, some might detail them.

Comment: I ask the question, because I know from God's teachings they are wrong! My question has also been doctored by curiousdanni to hide the factual theology of the scripture that proves my point. And if "truth" questions are not allowed, then it would appear that "lie" questions are allowed!

Comment: @Jason Alls  I had to edit my answer once spotting the edit to your Q. On here, Qs and As should not be pitched as if engaged in a verbal battle.  Nor should comments. This can be frustrating when one is sure their particular belief is true, and important. But although this is not a site designed to sort out "the truth" with Christian beliefs, that does not mean that it allows "lies". Answers are meant to give factual reasons, with proofs or, at least, back-up quotations to show the answer is not just voicing a personal opinion. Other sites encourage verbal spats; not this one!

Comment: @JasonAlls The site runs as it does because it runs on the Stack Exchange platform and must conform to their general guidelines. Any 'self-identifying' 'Christian' may use the site and become an administrator on the site. Thus, it is a site for 'comparative religion' asking questions about what people actually believe (not what 'truth' is, as such' ).

Comment: But as a Christian site, when erroneous beliefs are encountered, should they not be rectified with the truth. For Jesus is Truth, and the devil is the lie? There are very many beliefs among comparative religion. But before God there is only one true belief, and that belief is in God's absolute truth as presented in the Christian Bible. There are many human doctrines and traditions that contradict the scriptures. These contradictions work to undermine the Christian belief system that should be founded purely on the scriptures, is this not right?

Comment: @Jason Alls - No, this is not a Christian site. It is a site about Christianity. Big difference. It neither promotes Christianity nor attacks it. Neutrality is its stance. Participants are expected to answer questions about Christian views and practices, but questions, answers and comments are not to be used as a launch-pad for attacking particular views within Christianity. I agree with your last 5 sentences. It is your 1st one that is giving you difficulties in using this site, but please persevere in coming to grips with how to use it.